# Interpreting t-values in a categorical regression model: R

Tags: r, regression, categorical-data

I am having trouble understanding how to interpret t-values of a categorical variable in a multivariate regression. Please see an example below.

```
library(alr4)

a <- lm(I(log(acrePrice)) ~ I(as.factor(year)), data = MinnLand)

summary(a)
```

I am familiar with interpreting coefficients but not sure how to interpret t-values.

Comment: This question is so general that we must consider it answered in the duplicate thread; but if you have a more specific question to ask, please edit your post accordingly and we can reopen it.  But before you go to that effort, please research existing answers on our site, such as [these posts related to interpreting t values in regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=t+value+regression+interpret).

Comment: The posts do not consider a categorical variable in the regression. Moreover, there is a difference on the t-values you get when you run the standard regression in R and add a zero. I did not find a specific question regarding this. 
Again, I am not asking for a general interpretation of t-values. The t-values obtained by running regression (in the above example mentioned) is not the actual t-values. This is why I have asked a question.

Comment: "Add a zero" sounds like you are removing the intercept.  Search our site for questions about that situation -- there are very many posts about this topic.